# Twitter Feed in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, twitter, twitter-feed

I want to display the user's Twitter feed in the Flutter application. For that, I have created a Twitter developer's account and I am using  [twitter_api_v2](https://pub.dev/packages/twitter_api_v2) to get feed. But I am facing below error :

```
Authenticating with OAuth 2.0 Application-Only is forbidden for this endpoint.
Supported authentication types are [OAuth 1.0a User Context, OAuth 2.0 User Context]
```

I have also tried [dart_twitter_api](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_twitter_api) package. But didn't work.
Twitter account: Currently I enrolled only for a free account.
Can someone guide me, on how to resolve this error?

OR **How can we get user's entire feed listing? Without passing tweetIDs**

Comment: Sounds like you're using an application token when you should be using a user token.

Comment: Ok, How can I switch that?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your code.

Comment: Please add the code directly to the question, not as a screenshot.

Comment: That said, it appears your library recommends using https://pub.dev/packages/twitter_oauth2_pkce to get a user token.

Comment: @ceejayoz, I want to get user's feed (timeline), twitter_oauth2_pkce package is only provide me user token. What are the next steps?